# Convert character lat/lng values to numeric

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a data frame, `df`, with latitude and longitudinal character values with East, West, North, and South designations. What would be an elegant way to transform `df` into the desired output, `df2`, by transforming the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns as numeric and making any of the South and West values negative?

```
#MRE
library(tibble)

#input data set
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Capital, ~Latitude, ~Longitude,
  "Afghanistan", "Kabul", "34.28N", "69.11E",
  "Albania", "Tirane", "41.18N", "19.49E",
  "Algeria", "Algiers", "36.42N", "03.08E",
  "American Samoa", "Pago Pago", "14.16S", "170.43W",
  "Andorra", "Andorra la Vella", "42.31N", "01.32E",
  "Angola", "Luanda", "08.50S", "13.15E" 
  )

# desired output

df2 <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~Capital, ~Latitude, ~Longitude,
  "Afghanistan", "Kabul", 34.28, 69.11,
  "Albania", "Tirane", 41.18, 19.49,
  "Algeria", "Algiers", 36.42, 03.08,
  "American Samoa", "Pago Pago", -14.16, -170.43,
  "Andorra", "Andorra la Vella", 42.31, 01.32,
  "Angola", "Luanda", -08.50, -13.15 
  )
```

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions

Comment: heyydrien, do one of the answers resolve your question? If so, please don't forget to accept it. (If not, tell us what's different ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Latitude, Longitude),
            funs(as.numeric(gsub("[NE]$", "", gsub("^(.*)[WS]$", "-\\1", .)))))
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#          Country          Capital Latitude Longitude
#            <chr>            <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1    Afghanistan            Kabul    34.28     69.11
# 2        Albania           Tirane    41.18     19.49
# 3        Algeria          Algiers    36.42      3.08
# 4 American Samoa        Pago Pago   -14.16   -170.43
# 5        Andorra Andorra la Vella    42.31      1.32
# 6         Angola           Luanda    -8.50     13.15
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `tidyverse`. We can separate the `Longitude` and `Longitude` column to numbers and letters, and then add minus sign if it is "S" or "W".

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  separate(Latitude, into = c("Latitude", "Lat_Direction"), 
           sep = "(?=[A-Za-z])", convert = TRUE) %>%
  separate(Longitude, into = c("Longitude", "Long_Direction"), 
           sep = "(?=[A-Za-z])", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Latitude = ifelse(Lat_Direction %in% "S", -Latitude, Latitude),
         Longitude = ifelse(Long_Direction %in% "W", -Longitude,  Longitude)) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_Direction"))
df2
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   Country        Capital          Latitude Longitude
#   <chr>          <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Afghanistan    Kabul                34.3     69.1 
# 2 Albania        Tirane               41.2     19.5 
# 3 Algeria        Algiers              36.4      3.08
# 4 American Samoa Pago Pago           -14.2   -170.  
# 5 Andorra        Andorra la Vella     42.3      1.32
# 6 Angola         Luanda               -8.5     13.2
```

Comment: Nice solution but that formatting of output for a `tibble` seems really confusing: `-170.  ` to represent `-170.43` while `3.08` is shown in full?!? (nothing to do with you or your code obviously)

Comment: @thelatemail I think that is the default print setting of `tibble`. It is confusing. I never think about why it is designed that way. Perhaps I should study this a little bit.

Comment: I'm just having flashbacks to an old supervisor of mine suggesting I throw my report in the bin if I'm not going to consistently report values. Haha!

Comment: @thelatemail I agree with your old supervisor that consistency is important. Sometimes I added `as.data.frame()` in the last step of the pipe operation to have consistent view. Speaking of that, I am wondering how r2evans can print the `tibble` consistently in his answer?